# AWS Cloudfront error? invalidation max times while deploying?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, gitlab, gitlab-ci, amazon-cloudfront

I got the error while I'm deploying something from gitlab.

```
$ aws cloudfront create-invalidation --distribution-id=EVB1B2B3B4B56 --paths "/*"
**An error occurred (ServiceUnavailable) when calling the CreateInvalidation operation (reached max retries: 2): CloudFront encountered an internal error. Please try again.**
```

I sort it out by creating invalidation manually from AWS console and it works . This is the case happens sometimes causes this error, at that time I'm doing manually . What was the permanent solution ? Please help me to sort it out this.

Comment: https://repost.aws/questions/QUuKcJvRGeR2-vv2fL7NSv3Q/error-when-calling-aws-cloudfront-create-invalidation

Comment: there is no answer for that @Richard

Comment: "To find out the error cause, an investigation of the internal logs might be required. The best way for resolving such kind of issues is probably just contacting AWS Support, so the support team can look into this. Please open a support request."

Answer (score 17):

I experienced a similar issue when creating multiple invalidations while deploying the same application to many distributions. The error still happens randomly, sometimes just retrying the deployment later works fine, and others fail on a different distribution.

I [found a related issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/15891#issuecomment-966456154) showing the same error in the `github` `aws-cdk` repo, there seems to be an error with the `AWS Cloudfront API` during peak hours.

> From the CloudFront team:
>
> CreateInvalidation API suffers from high fault rate during the daily
> traffic peaks. It will return faults upto 50% of the requests. It is
> primarily due to the limited capacity of the API.
>
> We have evidence that some requests failed even after six retries ,
> during the peak. We are working on improving this , but there is no
> quick fix for this and we are expecting it will get better by the end
> of Q1 2022.

I still didn´t find a "clean" solution to this, what I have done is handle the error within my `CLI` script and automatically retry until it eventually succeeds.

Answer (score 13):

You can use increase the number of retries directly in your command:

```
AWS_MAX_ATTEMPTS=10 aws cloudfront create-invalidation --distribution-id=EVB1B2B3B4B56 --paths "/*"
```

You usually get this error when CloudFront API is experiencing a traffic peak. No guarantee to hit successfully the endpoint but you still have less chance to miss all the retries.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than increasing retry attempts, maybe a better idea is to introduce backoff/retry code into your deployment.

For example, when receiving the above error backoff and wait five minutes before attempting the invalidation again.

And given the number of people who configure cron jobs to run exactly on the hour, 30 minutes, etc., maybe chose a random minute value to run?

Comment: The AWS CLI does backoffs. "Any retry attempt will include an exponential backoff by a base factor of 2"