# How to increase AWS cloudfront invalidation max retries

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, aws-cli

From time to time when trying to create invalidation with **AWS CloudFront** (using a CI pipelines) with the following command:

```
aws cloudfront create-invalidation --distribution-id "${cloudfront_id}" --paths "/*"
```

I get the following error message:

```
An error occurred (ServiceUnavailable) when calling the CreateInvalidation operation (reached max retries: 2): CloudFront encountered an internal error. Please try again.
```

And a re-run of the CI pipeline usually works.

---

I am trying to figure out how to set a max retries that **is bigger than 2** (like the error message indicates) -

with the hope of it fixing it, since a re-run does work in those cases -

and\or fix it in some other way.

The [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudfront/create-invalidation.html) didn't had anything related or even the error specified..

Worth mentioning that the environment I am using is **GitHub Actions** on ubuntu-latest (which is currently at 22.04) with aws cli pre-installed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `max_attempts` in the AWS config, default location is: `~/.aws/config`

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-retries.html#cli-usage-retries-configure

Comment: Found in other thread you can also set the max_attemps in the command https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72287326/aws-cloudfront-error-invalidation-max-times-while-deploying